# Meteor Simple Schema - When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, schema

I keep getting the error: `Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator` when I try to create a user.  I am using meteor-simple-schema, but none of the fixes with this error have worked for me.  I have tried using blackbox and optional to see where the issue is but I keep getting the same error.

```
var Schemas = {};    
Schemas.UserGamesPart = {
  public: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: []
  },
  private: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: []
  }
};
Schemas.UserGames = {
  game1: {
    type: Schemas.UserGamesPart
  }
};
Schemas.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
  games: {
    type: Schemas.UserGames
  }
});
Schemas.UpgradeDetails = new SimpleSchema({
  subscribed_on: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true
  },
  stripe_charge_id: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  school_license: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false,
    optional: true
  }
});
Schemas.UserProperties = new SimpleSchema({
  paid: {
    type: Boolean,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  upgrade_details: {
    type: Schemas.UpgradeDetails,
    optional: true
  }
});

Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  emails: {
    type: [Object]
  },
  "emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
    optional: true
  },
  "emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schemas.UserProfile,
    blackbox: true,
    optional: true
  },
  properties: {
    type: Schemas.UserProperties,
    blackbox: true,
    optional: true
  }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schemas.User);
```

My accounts.creaate user is as follows:

```
Accounts.createUser({
  email: $('#email').val(),
  password: $('#password').val(),
  profile: {
    games: {
      game1: {
        public: [],
        private: []
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: You knew that accounts-base (a relevant meteor core-package) [already validates this stuff](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1276), right?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `new SimpleSchema` there in the beginning:

```
Schemas.UserGamesPart = new SimpleSchema({
  public: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: []
  },
  private: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: []
  }
});
Schemas.UserGames = new SimpleSchema({
  game1: {
    type: Schemas.UserGamesPart
  }
});
```

Also I think your usage of the nested schemas is a little off. *Only* nest schemas when you need to reuse one. Creating a separate schema for `UserGamesPart` looks horrible. Try this instead:

```
Schemas.UserGames = new SimpleSchema({
  game1: {
    type: Object
  }
  'game1.public': {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: []
  },
  'game1.private': {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: []
  }
});
```

This is shorter and easier to read.