# Error "Uncaught Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator" when trying to update

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm getting error message `Uncaught Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator`

I've looked at a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566429/validation-object-must-have-at-least-one-operator-meteor-mongo) of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032315/uncaught-error-when-the-modifier-option-is-true-validation-object-must-have-at) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093184/meteor-simple-schema-when-the-modifier-option-is-true-validation-object-must), but haven't been able to decipher what's wrong with my query:

```
Meteor.users.update({
    _id: Meteor.user()._id
}, {
    $set: {
        "emails.letter": true
    }
})
```

My MongoDB structure is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": "ujkwQp4rYTKQeLq3F",
    "emails": [{
        "address": "admin@admin.com",
        "letter": false
    }]
}
```

Comment: I think you're defining `emails` as an array, but acting like `letter` is a property. Try taking out the brackets so `emails` is an object. Does that help?

Comment: There might be multiple emails, all of which will have their own validations, so I can't change the model @terrafirma9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which element in the array you want to update. Try this:

```
Meteor.users.update({
    _id : 123456, 
    "emails.address":"admin@admin.com"
}, {
    $set: {
        "emails.$.letter": true
    }
});
```